# Export report with just one currency

Tags: reporting

I have a simple report that shows my opportunity with different currencies.

I'm exporting the report:
[image]

I would like to export this with just one currency.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

BR.

Answer (score 1):

There is another field on opportunity called **"Converted Amount"** this holds the amount of the opportunity but converted to the corporate currency.

The **Amount** field shows the local currency value of that opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Add converted Fields to the report, they are available for all currency fields (because multicurrency is enable).

After click Customize---Show-Currency Using---Select the currency.

This currency will be used by converted fields and grand totals.