# Currency conversion and Orders

Tags: multi-currency

Very similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13786/export-report-with-just-one-currency) post I would like to build a report that renders the amount in a single currency. My source object is Order - the amount is a custom field on Order. Advanced Currency Management is enabled.

Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Out of the box, [ACM manages fields on the Opportunity and a few related objects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm&type=5). If your Order amount comes from the Opportunity, you can take the ACM-converted (to whatever currency) monetary value from Opportunity to Order. Take = copy via Flow or render via a cross-object formula. Else, you'll need to implement your own currency conversion for your Order records.

Comment: this may help - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57659/2602

Comment: Thanks to both.